# C in CRUD for Silverlight

Tags: .net, vb.net, silverlight, crud

The C in CRUD Silverlight:

- Create new Silverlight business application "CRUD"
- Add ADO.NET Entity Data Model to CRUD.web
- Select the db, the tables, build the project
- Add Domain Service Class to CRUD.web
- Select the tables and also select the allow editing option for the table "tname"
- Build the project
- Keep two textboxes "ID" and "NAME" on MainPage.xaml
- Keep a button "SAVE NEW RECORD" on MainPage.xaml
- Build
- Add the following code

  ```
  Partial Public Class MainPage
      Inherits UserControl

      Dim dserv As New DomainService1

  //default methods generated
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
          'declare a table object
          Dim table As New tname
          'assign values to fields
          table.ID = TextBox1.Text
          table.NAME = TextBox2.Text
          'add table object entity
          dserv.tnames.Add(table)
          'submit the changes, to make it permenant in the db
          dserv.SubmitChanges()
      End Sub
  ```
- Record inserted

Is this the easiest way for having no side effects to add a new record? Is this the optimal way to add a new record?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's best-practice to put any logic that isn't strictly presentation-specific directly into a code-behind event handler like this, let alone that a `UserControl` knows anything about any `DomainService1` object.

If you're shooting for best-practices, you need to look into the *Model-View-ViewModel* pattern; it's not the job of any UI component to perform any kind of business or data logic.

Comment: Seems like the OP is more looking for what's **easiest** though.

Comment: @Simon true, but the post is also tagged [best-practices]

Comment: That's true, I would give you an upvote but I'm out of them for the time being (as usual).